# Execute dynamic prepared statement inside a trigger

Tags: postgresql

I want to use my trigger for logging purposes - every time, when a user inserts something or makes updates, there should appear a new row in my `history` table. I already have a trigger, which works good. Now it runs every time, when I do inserts. This is how it looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_history_insert()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
    ...
BEGIN
    ... it does a lot of things here and works absolutely correctly
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.trigger_history_insert()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Now I want to add logging into this trigger. I tried to follow these two official tutorials ([[1]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html), [[2]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html)), but ended in failure. This was my first attempt:

```
DECLARE
    ...
BEGIN
    ... everything remains unchanged except this part
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    const char *stmt = 'INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES (?)';
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;        
    EXEC SQL PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
    EXEC SQL EXECUTE mystmt USING new.field1;
END;
```

In this case I get syntax error pointing to this line of code:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
^
```

This was my second attempt:

```
BEGIN
    ... everything remains unchanged except this part
    BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    const char *stmt = 'INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES (?)';
    END DECLARE SECTION;        
    PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
    EXECUTE mystmt USING new.field1;
END;
```

Now, I get an error message pointing to this line:

```
BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
^
```

This was my third attempt:

```
$BODY$
DECLARE
    ...
    const char *stmt = 'INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES (?)'
BEGIN
    ...
    PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
    EXECUTE mystmt USING new.field1;
END
```

Now I get an error message pointing to this line:

```
const char *stmt = 'INSERT INTO history ...
^
```

This was my last attempt:

```
$BODY$
DECLARE
    ...
    stmt text := 'INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES (?)'
BEGIN
    ...
    PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
    EXECUTE mystmt USING new.field1;
END
```

And in this final case, the error message points to this line:

```
PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
               ^
```

So, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `do
$$
declare
stmt text;
begin
stmt := 'select null';
execute stmt;
end;
$$
;
` does this work for you?.. as an example of `EXEC` in pl/pGsql

Comment: Sorry, I have not checked it yet, but it seems like I've found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html), a language for writing functions in the database, and [ecpg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html), which is used for embedding database access in C client code.

The correct solution would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES (NEW.field1);
```

Comment: Actually, I found a solution: `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO history (field1) VALUES ($1)' USING new.field1;` But I guess, it is not a prepared statement in true sense of this word.

Comment: It is actually much simpler, see the updated answer. That would be a true prepared statement. What you suggest is *dynamic SQL* which is less efficient and prone to SQL injection problems.